# Android TV app Google Play publishing issue "Non-full screen static banner ads"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-tv

I'am trying publish my TV app on Google Play, but always get rejected status of release with next message:
*"Non-full screen static banner ads. Your app displays static banner ads which are not full screen."*

As I understood its about tv app icon, and not about advertising in my app (anyway it contains only full-screen video ADs in one player screen). But my app show banner correctly on Android TV Launcher screen. And I already put my 320 x 180px banner into xhdpi folder how they [recommend](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#banner), but every submitting attempt ends with this issue. My banner is not transparent and contain application name on it.

I believe I'm not the only one with this problem, please help me with google support, which only can answer *"I’m not able to provide any more details or a better answer to your question"*

[image: android manifest]

[image: folders]

**Google Play appeal answer:**

[image: google support answer]

Comment: this is most likely an issue between yourself and the playstore, i don't think there's a way we can help you here unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App is finally published, with ten appeals and one month, without any changes (just jpeg exchanged with png, but its not a solution of this problem).
So if you have similar problem, prepare to long war with google support bots.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯